# Extent Reports version 3.0.2 - AppendExisting

Tags: c#, .net, append, extentreports

Below is the code I am trying to use to append all tests to a single report. However, latest test is replacing all the older test reports. So, it's not appending to a single report for some reason. Can you please help me out here?

```
var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(ResourcesConfig.ReportPath);
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
            htmlReporter.LoadConfig(ResourcesConfig.ReportXMLPath);
            **htmlReporter.AppendExisting = true;**
```

Comment: This property has no implementation. AppendExisting is not supported by the C# binding.

Comment: Any update when this is going to be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with this as well as the documentation doesn't explain much. I have one method called ReportCreation which runs for every test case and in that method i have the following:

```
public static ExtentReports ReportCreation(){
    System.out.println(extent);
    if (extent == null) {
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        htmlReports = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName+ n + "\\extentReportFile.html");
        htmlReports.config().setReportName("Pre release Smoke test");
        htmlReports.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        htmlReports.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReports);
    }
    else {
        htmlReports = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName+ n+ "\\extentReportFile.html");
        htmlReports.setAppendExisting(true);
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReports);
    }
    return extent;
}
```

So when the first unit test is run, it will create the html report, but the second unit test will see that the report has already been generated and so use the existing one.

I have created a random number generator so that it goes to a different report on every run

```
public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static int n = rand.nextInt(10000)+1;
```

Comment: I have written my code in Java, hopefully you can use it to translate to c#

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. My solution was using .NET Core so ExtentReports 3 and 4 were not supported.

Instead, I wrote code to merge the results from previous html file to the new html file.

This is the code I used:

```
public static void GenerateReport()
        {
            // Publish test results to extentnew.html file
            extent.Flush();

            if (!File.Exists(extentConsolidated))
            {
                // Rename extentnew.html to extentconsolidated.html after execution of 1st batch
                File.Move(extentLatest, extentConsolidated);
            }
            else
            {
                // Append test results to extentconsolidated.html from 2nd batch onwards
                _ = AppendExtentHtml();
            }
        }

public static async Task AppendExtentHtml()
        {

            var htmlconsolidated = File.ReadAllText(extentConsolidated);
            var htmlnew = File.ReadAllText(extentLatest);

            var config = Configuration.Default;
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

            var newdoc = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlnew));
            var newlis = newdoc.QuerySelector(@"ul.test-list-item");

            var consolidateddoc = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlconsolidated));
            var consolidatedlis = consolidateddoc.QuerySelector(@"ul.test-list-item");

            foreach (var li in newlis.Children)
            {
                li.RemoveFromParent();
                consolidatedlis.AppendElement(li);
            }

            File.WriteAllText(extentConsolidated, consolidateddoc.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
        }
```

This logic bypasses any Extent Report reference and treats the result file as any other html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Jaideep Dhumal updated based on ExtentReport 4.1.0:

```
/// <summary>Appends test results to consolidated report.</summary>
/// <param name="consolidatedReportPath">Full pathname of the consolidated report file.</param>
/// <param name="reportPath">The Path to the Report.</param>
/// <returns>A Task.</returns>
/// <example>.</example>
private static async Task AppendToConsolidatedReport(string consolidatedReportPath, string reportPath)
{
    var htmlConsolidated = File.ReadAllText(consolidatedReportPath);
    var htmlNew = File.ReadAllText(reportPath);
    var config = Configuration.Default;
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
    var newDoc = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlNew));
    var newLis = newDoc.QuerySelector(@"ul.test-collection");
    var consolidatedDoc = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlConsolidated));
    var consolidatedLis = consolidatedDoc.QuerySelector(@"ul.test-collection");
    var consolidatedTests = new List<string>();
    if (consolidatedLis != null)
    {
        foreach (var li in consolidatedLis.Children)
        {
            // record what we already have in the consolidated list to avoid duplication
            var existingTestName = li.QuerySelector(@"span.test-name");
            var existingTestTime = li.QuerySelector(@"span.test-time");
            if (existingTestName != null && existingTestTime != null)
            {
                consolidatedTests.Add(existingTestName.InnerHtml + existingTestTime.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
    }
    if (newLis != null && consolidatedLis != null)
    {
        foreach (var li in newLis.Children)
        {
            // check we don't already have it in the consolidated list (this can happen if this method is called twice)
            var newTestName = li.QuerySelector(@"span.test-name");
            var newTestTime = li.QuerySelector(@"span.test-time");
            if (newTestName == null || newTestTime == null ||
                consolidatedTests.Contains(newTestName.InnerHtml + newTestTime.InnerHtml)) continue;
            li.RemoveFromParent();
            consolidatedLis.AppendElement(li);
        }
    }
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(consolidatedReportPath, consolidatedDoc.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
}
```