# Extent reports not appending after suite test run.... Is AppendExisting implemented?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0, extent, selenium-extent-report

I'm on the latest version 3.1.3(I even downgraded the version) Can someone verify that this "AppendExisting" property is implemented. I read here that it wasn't:[C# AppendExisting binding not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372441/extent-reports-version-3-0-2-appendexisting)

Can someone confirm that this is implemented??? I spent over a day trying to get this to work and it seems not implemented. I see in the debugger that it is being set...

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented. Setting that property will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This property is not supported in C# binding.